# Aligning a form to center that is inside a VBox

Tags: sapui5

I have a simple form, that is inside a VBox. Now if I try to set Align Items to Center, the form in desktop view breaks down to Label and Input in separate lines. However if alignitems is set to "Stretched" it works fine, but since I have custom width for Input Boxes, I need to align it to the center in Mobile View as well.
Please Help.

Comment: try vbox property called justifyContent="Center" which place all content in vbox to center

Comment: Tried. Didn't work, found a work around by setting padding classes for the right. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it with custom CSS. Add in your manifest.json within the sap.ui5 property this

```
"resources": {
    "css": [
        {
            "uri": "css/style.css"
        }
    ]
}
```

Give your Simple Form in the view an ID. Create the style.css at the in the manifest.json given uri. Access the Simple Form within the style.css. Align it via the style.css to the center, e.g. margin: 0 auto;